# undefined method `gsub' for :user:Symbol rails 4 devised nested form fields

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, nested-forms

Rails 4.1, Ruby 2.1.1 Ubuntu 12.04

I just created a new Rails 4 app and I am using Devise for user authentication, and a gem called [nested_form_fields](https://rubygems.org/gems/nested_form_fields) to add multiple form fields to sign up form. Before I added the nested form fields the sign worked, but when I added the code from the nested_form_fields gem I started getting the following error when I submit the form

```
undefined method `gsub' for :user:Symbol
```

According to the stack trace this is the offending line of code.

```
<%= f.nested_fields_for :members do |m| %>
```

Here is the code from the sign in form.

```
<div class="authform">
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
    <h3>Sign up</h3>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :band_name, "Band Name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :band_name, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
      <%= f.nested_fields_for :members do |m| %>
        <%= m.label :first_name, "First Name" %>
        <%= m.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= m.remove_nested_fields_link 'Remove Member', class: 'form-control' %>
      <% end %>
    <%= f.add_nested_fields_link :members, class: 'button right' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Sign up', :class => 'button right' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :members
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :members, allow_destroy: true
end
```

And the nested resource model

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And the server log

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `gsub' for :user:Symbol:
  nested_form_fields (0.5.0) lib/nested_form_fields.rb:91:in `association_path'
  nested_form_fields (0.5.0) lib/nested_form_fields.rb:87:in `template_id'
  nested_form_fields (0.5.0) lib/nested_form_fields.rb:73:in `nested_model_template'
  nested_form_fields (0.5.0) lib/nested_form_fields.rb:57:in `fields_for_has_many_association_with_template'
  nested_form_fields (0.5.0) lib/nested_form_fields.rb:21:in `nested_fields_for'
  app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:21:in `block in _app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__1744019853585419741_70197629148340'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:434:in `form_for'
  app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__1744019853585419741_70197629148340'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:338:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:142:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:238:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:165:in `to_html'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:158:in `respond'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:151:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:400:in `respond_with'
  devise (3.2.3) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:8:in `new'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:551:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:87:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0.rc1) lib/rails/engine.rb:515:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0.rc1) lib/rails/application.rb:142:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

And the full trace

```
nested_form_fields (0.5.0) lib/nested_form_fields.rb:91:in `association_path'
nested_form_fields (0.5.0) lib/nested_form_fields.rb:87:in `template_id'
nested_form_fields (0.5.0) lib/nested_form_fields.rb:73:in `nested_model_template'
nested_form_fields (0.5.0) lib/nested_form_fields.rb:57:in `fields_for_has_many_association_with_template'
nested_form_fields (0.5.0) lib/nested_form_fields.rb:21:in `nested_fields_for'
app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:21:in `block in _app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__24818471064349848_70035465677100'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:434:in `form_for'
app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__24818471064349848_70035465677100'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:338:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:142:in `render'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:238:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:165:in `to_html'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:158:in `respond'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:151:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:400:in `respond_with'
devise (3.2.3) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:8:in `new'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:551:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:87:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.0.rc1) lib/rails/engine.rb:515:in `call'
railties (4.1.0.rc1) lib/rails/application.rb:142:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Can you share the server log for when you get this error.

Comment: You should expand your stack trace to include library code, and figure out the actual offending line. We can't help you based on what's been posted so far.

Comment: Without a stack trace this is really shooting in the dark.

Comment: I've posted the server log and the full stack trace as requested.

Comment: can you post app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:21 ?

Comment: fwidtmann here is that line:

<%= f.nested_fields_for :members do |m| %>